# How to compile kernel module without a makefile?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, make, gcc

Is it possible to compile a kernel module without a makefile and if so, how?

Comment: Certainly yes, because `make` is simply running commands (e.g. compilation commands) described by the `Makefile`/

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible because the kernel Makefile that you have to use to compile a module has to call another Makefile defining `obj-m`.

The usual Makefile for an out of tree module loks like that:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
obj-m := mymodule.o
else
KDIR := /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build

all:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$$PWD
endif
```

The first time it is called, `KERNELRELEASE` is not defined, it will then call the kernel Makefile with the `M=$$PWD` parameter.
Finally, the kernel Makefile will use `M`, finding and calling the module Makefile again, this time with `KERNELRELEASE` defined and obj-m will get filled. The module will then be compiled.